# How do I view and share a running Angular app through Vagrant?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, vagrant

I have a basic Angular app installed using a Yeoman fullstack installer, and I can see the basic pages running on `http://localhost:9000` when I run 'grunt serve'.

I also have a Vagrant installation running using the ubuntu/trusty64 box. I was originally seeing a 404 when trying to view `http://127.0.0.1:4567/`, but following some instructions I found online, I edited the file in 'vagrant ssh' at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf by removing the html part of the path in that file. After doing 'vagrant reload' I now see the list of files in my project dir when I go to that URL.

How do I go about viewing my angular app like it is at `localhost:9000`? If I get this working will this mean that if I share via Vagrant, they'll see the angular app running as it should? Do I still need to be running grunt serve in combination with Vagrant?

I'm pretty new to all this setup, so I'm just following the instructions at https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack & https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html

I'm not great with Linux/cmd line stuff as yet, hence my problems... :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I started writing instructions for you on how to get it done. But then realised that you are not very comfortable with linux commands. I have created a [angular-seed project](https://github.com/adikari/angular-seed) that uses `vagrant`, `angular` and `requirejs`. Its easy to set up and I have written instructions on how to do that in my [github page](https://github.com/adikari/vagrant-seed).

Just clone it, follow the instruction and you will have a working seed project in no time. Some of the features of the seed are:

Uses `vagrant` and `puppet` to provision the vm. All required dependencies are automatically installed.

Grunt tasks for:

- autoloading bower dependencies
- compile sass or scss
- livereload
- server for access of site locally

If you have any difficulties or questions, feel free to contact me.